# html5 geolocation locationError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

**i am trying to get geolocation with google maps API ,but failed 
came across the problem that `Error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:`**

here goes my code

What is causing this error to happen and where can I start researching for ways to fix problem?

```js
 function findYou() {
   if (!navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,
     noLocation, {
       maximumAge: 1200000,
       timeout: 30000
     })) {
     document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML =
       "This browser does not support geolocation.";
   }
 }

 function showPosition(location) {
   var latitude = location.coords.latitude;
   var longitude = location.coords.longitude;
   var accuracy = location.coords.accuracy;
   // 创建地图
   var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   // 创建地图选项
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 18,
     center: position,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
   };
   // 显示地图
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
     myOptions);
   document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML =
     "Your latitude is " + latitude;
   document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML =
     "Your longitude is " + longitude;
   document.getElementById("acc").innerHTML =
     "Accurate within " + accuracy + " meters";
 }

 function noLocation(locationError) {
   var errorMessage = document.getElementById("lat");
   switch (locationError.code) {
     case locationError.PERMISSION_DENIED:
       errorMessage.innerHTML =
         "You have denied my request for your location.";
       break;
     case locationError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
       errorMessage.innerHTML =
         "Your position is not available at this time.";
       break;
     case locationError.TIMEOUT:
       errorMessage.innerHTML =
         "My request for your location took too long.";
       break;
     default:
       errorMessage.innerHTML =
         "An unexpected error occurred.";
   }
 }
 findYou();
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML5 Geolocation</title>
  <style>
  </style>
  <!--set the api -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Your Location</h1>

  <p id="lat">&nbsp;</p>
  <p id="lon">&nbsp;</p>
  <p id="acc">&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use the insert snippet tool button on above the editor where you write in answers to insert HTML/CSS/JS snippets that will be highlighted and formatted automatically (makes it easier for us to read at the very least)

Comment: The posted code works for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7a7ejL6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing you script reference to this in your HTML page,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
```